# Test flight sending email notification after app release | iOS

Tags: ios, email, app-store-connect, testflight, apple-developer

I'm using test flight to share builds with internal testers. But I noticed a weird behavior last week.

I deployed a build almost a month ago, and now the app is live with that build. However, Testflight sent an automated email to testers again saying the build is available for testing. (I know that in current version, we may test the app even if it's live).

The question is:

1. Is it some bug at test-flight's end that it's sending email notification of
   an old build again?
2. Should I manually expire this build to avoid any
   such issue in future? Please note, my app is live with this build
   and I don't want it to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Same thing just happened to me, but almost 48 hours after I released the app. I don't even have any Testflight users other than me.

I had to double-check to make sure it was really in the App Store. Must be a bug...